# Ошибка Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: drupal

Модифицировал модуль для Drupal 7 вылазит ошибка

> Notice: Trying to get property of
> non-object в функции
> context_geoip_condition->execute()
> (строка 50 в файле
> /var/www/mailfox/sites/all/modules/context_geoip/context_geoip_condition.inc)

код начиная с 45 строки

```
function execute() {  
    if ($this->condition_used()) {
      $record = geoip_city();
        foreach ($this->get_contexts() as $context) {
        $city_names = $this->fetch_from_context($context, 'values');
        if (in_array($record->city, $city_names)) {
          $this->condition_met($context);
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

[Скачать сам модуль](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13528405/context_geoip.zip)

Answer (score 1):

$record не является объектом. Скорее всего, geoip_city() возвращает false, потому что по каким-то причинам не справился с задачей (например, видит айпи 127.0.0.1), и для этого надо предусмотреть случай, когда geoip_city() не справился (добавить проверку на false).

Comment: дело в том что этот модуль отлично работает на drupal 6

Comment: @mailfox, ок, как это меняет дело?

Comment: Вот и сам хочу разобраться... в принципе все должно работать гуд
@Fike как вы предлагаете реализовать проверку?

Comment: пц  

    if ($record === false)
        return false;

Comment: @Fike и что это мне даст как мне узнать где отловить причину ошибки в какие логи смотреть

Comment: > и что это мне даст

избежите ошибки, одновременно сохраняя отчет о ней в виде возвращаемого значения

> где отловить причину ошибки

в geoip_city()

> в какие логи смотреть

вы хотите, чтобы я по куску абстрактного кода сказал, в какие логи пишет функция, чей код я даже не видел?

Comment: ну что господин @Fike все фичи кончились... если бы было легко то я бы не писал ) тем более у вас есть возможность скачать код и запустить его удаленно http://simplytest.me/